# how to compare columns and to count in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql. i need to compare columns in a table

I use MySQL 8.0 and only one database

```
create table A
(
   serial_no           varchar(10),
   p01_pass_fail       varchar(4),
   p02_pass_fail       varchar(4),
   p03_pass_fail       varchar(4),
   p04_pass_fail       varchar(4),
   p05_pass_fail       varchar(4)
)
```

if a row is:

```
serial_no = 001,
p01_pass_fail = pass,
p02_pass_fail = fail,
p03_pass_fail = pass,
p04_pass_fail = pass,
p05_pass_fail = fail
```

My perfect result is pass count = 3, fail count = 2

it is not easy for me

Comment: including the table definition is a great start.  It's not clear what you want to compare and beyond the `create table`, what your text is supposed to mean.  What's your query so far and in what does it result?  What exactly do you want the results to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach for this will be making boolean expressions like `p01_pass_fail = "pass"` and then sum the boolean results of these expression:

```
SELECT
    serial_no,
    ((p01_pass_fail = 'pass') +
     (p02_pass_fail = 'pass') +
     (p03_pass_fail = 'pass') +
     (p04_pass_fail = 'pass') +
     (p05_pass_fail = 'pass')) AS pass_count,
    ((p01_pass_fail = 'fail') +
     (p02_pass_fail = 'fail') +
     (p03_pass_fail = 'fail') +
     (p04_pass_fail = 'fail') +
     (p05_pass_fail = 'fail')) AS fail_count
FROM
    A
```

You can check next sample with data also: [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dm7S3nQ53XqgTY63oHsJfw/0)

Comment: @KKIM Please, take into consideration to upvote the answers that were useful to you and to check one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE ... END` to "translate" `'pass'` or `'fail'` to `1` or `0` and `+` to sum it up.

```
SELECT serial_no,
       CASE p01_pass_fail
         WHEN 'fail' THEN
           0
         WHEN 'pass' THEN
           1
       END
       +
       ...
       +
       CASE p05_pass_fail
         WHEN 'fail' THEN
           0
         WHEN 'pass' THEN
           1
       END pass_count,
       CASE p01_pass_fail
         WHEN 'pass' THEN
           0
         WHEN 'fail' THEN
           1
       END
       +
       ...
       +
       CASE p05_pass_fail
         WHEN 'pass' THEN
           0
         WHEN 'fail' THEN
           1
       END fail_count
       FROM a;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your table design to this:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    serial_no varchar(10),
    p01_pass_fail tinyint,
    p02_pass_fail tinyint,
    p03_pass_fail tinyint,
    p04_pass_fail tinyint,
    p05_pass_fail tinyint
)
```

Then, store 0 for a fail and 1 for a pass.  This greatly simplifies the query:

```
SELECT
    serial_no,
    cnt AS pass,
    5 - cnt AS fail
FROM
(
    SELECT,
        serial_no,
        p01_pass_fail + p02_pass_fail + p03_pass_fail + p04_pass_fail + p05_pass_fail AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
) t
```

The labels `pass` and `fail` are really presentation things and do not belong in your data model.  If you want to convert an integer 0/1 score to a label, you may still do so via a `CASE` expression, e.g.

```
CASE WHEN p01_pass_fail = 1 THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END
```

Comment: That is a really good recommendation if he can change the schema of the table. +1

Comment: oh, i didn't know that but this system already used varchar type ;( thks